# [Azure AD]: Reset Password button Disabled

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I was Login as a Global Administrator i was select the user and try to reset the password. but, the password reset button is disabled. how can i enable the reset password button. Azure AD.

[image: Rest Password]

i was disable any permission in dashboard or any other reason for disable in reset password. Anyone know share me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The user you select is a guest user(external user) in your tenant ?

Comment: @NanYu Thank you  it's working it's page loading time it's disable. after few second after only it's enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the user that you want to reset password for is an external user.

You **cannot reset the password for  the users that from external**, such as guest users

You can reset internal users that are in your Azure AD .External users can reset their passwords by themselves in the login website.

Comment: i was try the internal users for password reset not guest users. the internal user and guest user also reset password button is disabled

Comment: Thank you, it's working it's page loading time it's disable after few second after  only it's enable.

Answer (score 1):

If the user account in question is an internal user, i.e the user UPN would end with either the default domain of the tenant or a verified custom domain – you would be able to reset the password as a GA. However, if the user belongs to another tenant you would not have the access to reset the password. Also, the same applies to Guest Users as explained by Wayne.

In this case, you could ask the user in question to visit https://aka.ms/sspr for Self Service Password Reset.